# Webpack not compiling - Module build failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am just setting up my dev environment for my **react.js app** and i've run into an error where webpack is refusing to compile. I am getting the error **Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token at line 5**. And line 5 is `render (<App />, document.getElementById('app'));`. I've added `<script type="text/babel>"` to my script tag on my **index.html** but i'm still getting the same error.

Here's my **webpack.config.js:**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './src'
  ],
  output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
      modules: ['node_modules', 'src'],
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
},  
module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader']
    }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()

};
```

My **app.js:**

```
import React from 'react';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <h1>My React App</h1>
          </div>

      );
   }
}
```

And my **index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/app';

render ( <App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

What i'm i doing wrong?

Comment: can you show what is in your .babelrc file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding a .babelrc file with:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

Then do:

```
npm i --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
npm i --save-dev babel-preset-react
```

Make sure you have `babel-loader` installed too.

Comment: Thanks. This works!, in the sense that the error is no longer there. (Though it threw an error initially because you missed out the curly braces). But nothing is displaying on the screen.

Comment: Fixed that. I had commented out the plugins. Removed the comment tags and it works. Kindly edit your answer and add curly braces around the array. Also remove the comma at the end of the square bracket.